# XML what can I substitute a ( and ) for in the tag name

Tags: html, xml, web-scraping

I'm scraping some HTML and placing the data into an xml doc (essentially a bunch of <li><a>something</a></li> tags. Some of these have text like so <li><a>This is (stuff)</a></li>

So my scraper was making it <This_is_(stuff)>, which was being rejected when I pulled the xml up in my browser. What can I use in lieu of the ( ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh. I just took the contents of the parentheses and placed it in an attribute. Been a while since I toyed with XML.